# How are StanfordNER Classifiers built

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am working with StanfordNER classifiers. There are 4 classifiers as

```
english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
example.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz
```

How are these classifiers built? Since each of them is based on a different corpus, here is my guess

1. Train a machine learning classifier like `SVM` coupled with `OVR` (for multi label case) on the corpus to detect entities like `ORGANIZATION`,`PERSON`,`LOCATION` etc. This means that the training data would be the entire text of a document in the corpus. For that piece of text we explicitly indicate the `ORGANIZATION`s,`PERSON`s and `LOCATION`s. Thus the classifiers would be able to predict those entities.
2. Train a machine learning classifier to link POS tags with entities like `ORGANIZATION`,`PERSON`,`LOCATION`. For example, a classifier can be trained to predict which proper nouns should be `ORGANIZATION`

Is this the correct big picture? I am just trying to work out how to build my own NER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the models are trained on supervised data. They're 1st order CRFs which do multi-class probabilistic sequence classification (so not OVR, not SVM). You can find an introduction to NER and Stanford NER in particular on [the Stanford NER page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml).

Comment: thanks @Christopher Manning. A quick follow up, which version of conll is the conll classifier based on? i mean is it based on CoNLL-2003 shared task? I know that the CoNLL-2000 shared task was based on Reuters data. What data set is the basis for `english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz`? Similarly for the `english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz`

Comment: CoNLL 2003 shared task. Also based on Reuters data